# Change the renderer of a JRChart in a precompiled Jasperreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I am creating a Jasper report template in IReport which I'm compiling and filing using a Java application.

On a scatter chart I want to plot a regression line as a spline. Currently, the only way I found to do this was using the JFreeCharts [XYSplineRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYSplineRenderer.html). However, this requires me to create the chart in my Java code and then pass it to the report as a parameter while filling it. This also requires me to customize the appearance of my chart in the code.

I would like to be able to design my chart inside the jrxml with IReport, compile the report in Java, fetch the chart object and set a custom renderer to it before filling it.

Something like this:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportIs);
JRChart jrChart = (JRChart) report.getSummary().getElementByKey("chart");
JFreeChart chart = jrChart.getJFreeChart(); // this method does not exist
((XYPlot)chart.getPlot()).setRenderer(new XYSplineRenderer());
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to retrieve an actual JFreeChart object from a compiled report, nor can I find any other method to pass a custom plot renderer to a chart.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a chart customizer to accomplish this. It allows you to access the chart as a `JFreeChart` (as well as a `JRChart`) which should be just what you need. Add a chart customizer to your chart by setting the `customizerClass` attribute. The `customize` method is called by Jasper and allows you to modify the chart during the report filling process.

Create a customizer that looks something like this:

```
public class MyChartCustomizer implements JRChartCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart jFreeChart, JRChart jRChart) {
        ((XYPlot)jFreeChart.getPlot()).setRenderer(new XYSplineRenderer());
    }
}
```

Then compile it and make sure that it's on Jasper's classpath when you come to fill the report.

Comment: Great! Looks just like what I needed! I'll let you know how it goes.